# Flutter doctor --android-license Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

For mac I got issue with flutter config --android-studio-dir= is not a good path to my AndroidStudio Directory

Answer (score 0):

I just type on my terminal to restart the path to AndroidStudio Directory

> flutter config --android-studio-dir=

I found many peoples have problem with this and then with SDK manager

> For SDK manager just included in SDK Tools in AndroidStudio all packages instead of NDK

if you include NDK then you will have a problem with build Android App